# No type named "" in ""

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

My code is below.

```
class A
{
    enum kind { cpu, gpu };

    A(int a)
    {
        value = a;
    }

private:
    int value;
};

class B 
{
    A a;
    A b(A::cpu);
};
```

This code will occur error. I know instance the class A as a member of B is an error, but this hint makes me confused.

[image]

In face, it is nothing to do with private:
[image]

Comment: `enum kind` is a privately defined enum in class `A`. Add `public:` specifier to make it accessible from outside of class `A`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems:

- `kind` is private in `A` (it's a class, by default private), so you need to declare it public first to use it in `B`.
- The location where you declare `b` is inside a class, where variables and methods are declared. The compiler thinks you declare a function, when you actually want to default-initialize the object. Use `A b{A::cpu};` instead (curly braces).

Comment: I think you should note that default access specifier is `private` for classes and `public` for structs

Comment: Thanks @Ayxan, indeed better to specify this.